# Sending wordpress title-value across PHP-pages

Tags: php

I recently made this wordpress blog, where you can sign up a team for an event, when clicking a link under the event post. This link takes you to a sign-up form on another php-page. The link is added in the loop of the events-template like this:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=8');?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div id="tilmeldknap"><?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&depth=1&include=63"); ?></div>
        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>...
```

So every upcoming event will have the same sign-up button.
All I need now is to somehow send the specific event-post-title along to the sign-page, so that the following form-submit action will contain that title aswell.  But since I'm not very good at php it seems like a mystery, altho I bet it's very simple!

I'm guessing it's something like:

```
$event=$_POST['single_post_title()']
```

But how to get the value to the next php-page I have no idea... please help, anyone :)

An eksample can be seen throught this link: http://gadebold.dk/events/
The link sais: 'Tilmeld Hold'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a form, which I am assuming that you are, you can use hidden fields..

```
<!-- assuming you are using page slugs -->
<form method='post' action='<?php echo site_url('\sign-up\')?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='post_title' value='<?php echo single_post_title() ?>'>
....<!-- rest of form -->
</form>
```

And at the receiving page,

```
<?php

  $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];

 ?>
```

If you are not using a button, you can embed the page title in the URL and send using $_GET

```
<a href='<?php echo site_url('\sign_up\').'?title='.single_post_title()?>'>Register</a>

 ....
$post_title = $_GET['post_title'];
```

As a side-note, the [Pods CMS](http://podscms.org/) is a great plugin for doing systems like this, and may help to reduce development time.

Comment: There is a typo in line 3 of your code where you close the `<input>` twice - before the value-attribute and after it again.

Comment: Okay, I tried to embed the title in the URL, but it doesn't show.
Putting in another value instead of .single_post_title() makes that show, so it's as if single-post-title() has no value...

Comment: Tried your first method with the hidden input and submitted it using the_title() instead and that seemed to work... thx